# Delete emails from server Mac Mail

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have setup and email account on Mac mail. The account accesses email through IMAP. One of the settings for the account is not to keep any messages on the server under the advanced tab in Mac Mail.

However no emails are being deleted on the server once they are received on Mac mail client.

Any clue on where I can check the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The only folders you can keep locally for IMAP are:

- Drafts
- Sent
- Trash
- Spam

If you want to empty other IMAP mailboxes, you will want to set up local folders on the Mac - use the built in help and search for "Create Mailbox" to get the steps to make a local folder so you can move all the messages there and then send a delete command to the IMAP server to actually remove them if they don't auto purge.